# Some code which must run even if the web application is closed in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to run a code only on 28th of every month. 
I want to update some table and insert some data on this date. 
My web app is a investment web.

Answer (score 0):

You must schedule a task in cron. If your hosting is cpanel / WHM for example, you can on your cpanel go to the cron link and schedule the script to run for the desired day.

See how it would look like a schedule to run a script every day 28 at 4:00 am.

> 0 4   28  *   *   php /home/meulogin/script.php

See more information at the link below:

https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/2198/~/setting-up-cron-jobs-in-cpanel